# How to mass-replace text in "sounds" : ["test/test"]

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to make a resource pack in Minecraft, and I'm replacing it so there's only one sound. When I went to go and edit sounds.json in VSC, I want to set all the locations to just one file. It should look like this :

```
"sounds" : [
"test/test"
],
```

to `test/test` for all the "sounds". But I have no idea of how to do this. The sounds.json file is so big it would take more than a day to do all the work by hand. So I checked to see if VSC had any options to replace the text. There wasn't.

I've tried looking around in VSC and there wasn't anything useful.

I've tried replacing all the sounds by pasting .ogg files and renaming them, it took too long, so I realized I could just set all the locations to point at one sound file.

I've gone on Google to do some research but found nothing of use.

```
  "block.enderchest.open": {
    "sounds": [
      "test/test"
    ],
    "subtitle": "subtitles.block.chest.open"
  },
  "block.fence_gate.close": {
    "sounds": [
      "block/fence_gate/close1",
      "block/fence_gate/close2"
    ],
    "subtitle": "subtitles.block.fence_gate.toggle"
  },
  "block.fence_gate.open": {
    "sounds": [
      "block/fence_gate/open1",
      "block/fence_gate/open2"
    ],
    "subtitle": "subtitles.block.fence_gate.toggle"
  },
  "block.fire.ambient": {
    "sounds": [
      "fire/fire"
    ],
```

I expect a convenient way in order to edit `"sounds" : []` []'s all at once.

The actual result is not really a convenient way and a time waster to edit all of the sounds [] values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is with regex, see [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/9vHZP4/5).

Search for : `("sounds": \[\n)((\s*)[^\]]*\n)*(\s*\],)`

Replace with: `$1$3"test/test"\n$4`

[image: vscode regex replace demo]